# Add to DB selected value in JSP drop down using JSTL

Tags: jsp, select, drop-down-menu, jstl

Good day!

I have a list of violations and form, where this violations are shown in drop down list. List "violation" has 2 attributes: violationDescription and idViolation. When I select one of violationDescription and press button Save I need to get it's idViolation and send it to controller. I need it to add a new violation to my table Post, which collect violations, dates and other information. How can I do that?

```
List<ViolationsEntity> violation = violationsDao.findAllByOrderByViolationDescriptionAsc();
model.addObject("violations", violation);
```

form.jsp

```
<form:select path="classificators">
    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select violation---" />
        <c:forEach items="${violations}" var="violation">
            <form:option value="${violation.violationDescription}"/>
        </c:forEach>           
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, hope it can helps someone

```
$(function () {
    var violations = {

        <c:forEach items="${violations}" var="violation" varStatus="violationId">
            '${violation.idViolation}': '<c:out value="${violation.violationDescription}"/>',
        </c:forEach>
    };

    $("select")
        .change(function () {
            var str = "";
            $( "select option:selected" ).each(function () {
                str += $( this ).val();
            });
            console.log(violations[str])
            $( "#output" ).text( violations[str] );
        })
})
```

```
<div id="output"></div>
```